# What is the variance of $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{N+1}$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, variance, covariance

Let $X_1,X_2,\cdots$ be a sequence of independent normally distributed random variables with mean 1 and variance 1. Let $N$ be a Poisson random variable with mean $2$, independent of $X_1,X_2,\cdots$. Then, the variance of $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{N+1}$ is ?

> My attempt:

We know that $\text{Var}(aX_1+bX_2)=a^2\text{Var}(X_1)+b^2\text{Var}(X_2)$ when $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. 
And for a poisson random variable $X_n$, mean=variance=$\lambda$.
So, in our case $\text{Var}(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{N+1})=n+2$. I believe this is wrong, as the answer is a constant (independent of $N$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the total law of variance:

\begin{align}
Var\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N+1} X_i\right] &= E\left[ Var\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{N+1}X_i|N\right] \right] + Var\left[ E\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{N+1}X_i|N\right] \right]\\
&= E \left[ N+1\right] + Var(N+1)
\end{align}

I will leave the rest to you.

Comment: I am unable to solve. Can you please complete the solution, it will be very helpful.

Comment: hmmm... do you know the mean and variance of $N$?

Comment: not true. hmmm... do you know the distribution of $N$?

Comment: No, i don't know.

Comment: read the first two lines of the question again. (btw, I need to run some errand, slow in response, but I will get back to you after I get home).

Comment: Ok. Please try to complete it, if you can. By that time I will try to figure out as suggested by you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106598/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-s1mple).

Answer (score 1):

By defining $$Y_N=X_1+X_2+\cdots +X_{N+1}$$we can say that $$Y_N|N=n\sim \mathcal{N}(n+1,n+1)$$
hence $$E\{Y_N\}{=E_N\Big\{E_{Y_N}\{Y_n|N\}\Big\}\\=E_N\{N+1\}=3}$$also$$E\{Y^2_N\}{=E_N\Big\{E_{Y^2_N}\{Y^2_n|N\}\Big\}\\=E_N\{N+1+(N+1)^2\}
\\=E_N\{N^2+3N+2\}
\\=6+6+2
=14}$$hence $$\sigma^2_{Y_n}=5$$

Comment: I am unable to solve. Can you please complete the solution, it will be very helpful.

Comment: Sure. I've added more details. You can also read more about Poisson distribution here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution